# Proving an answer is correct

Tags: discussion

Being a Stack Overflow user, I have noticed that it is quite easy to see for myself whether an answer is right or wrong; I just need to test it. I've seen many answers today, but since in some countries the sources are scarce, one can not actually know whether the answers given are correct. Isn't there a need for citations in most answers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a site that needs to be heavily citation-driven. Everybody has heard their own version of their mythological tale of choice, but much of this is filtered through retelling upon retelling, with the end result being that one's recollection of a given myth could well be wildly-divorced from what the source texts actually claim. Citations of the source texts are the only real solution.

For a model of what this site should aspire to, I think that everyone should look at [Keshav Srinivasan's [mythology] answers on Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a36%20mythology%20is%3aanswer). Keshav's answers are, without exception, *beautifully* cited, and often accompanied by suitably-lengthy quotations from the relevant sourcetext.